# linear programming algorithm for maximum proceeds

Tags: math, optimization, linear-programming

You can find the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARF7Y.png)

First, I would assign a variable (x or y) to each quantity that is being solved for, and likewise write an equation for the quantity that is being maximized or minimized (cost, profit, amount, etc.) and call this the maximization or minimization equation. Then, I would have to write each constraint as an inequality, and number each inequality and graph the system, numbering each line on the graph as its corresponding inequality.

This should yield a shaded solution region with several "corners." Each corner is the intersection of two constraint inequalities. I would have to find the coordinates of the corners by solving the systems of intersecting equations.

Using the found coordinates, I would then plug the coordinates of the corners into the maximization/minimization equation. The coordinates that give the largest or smallest value for this equation (depending on what the problem is looking for, and in this case the maximum proceeds) are the solution to the problem.

Could anyone provide a rough hint or pseudocode for it? I know the rough outline of what I have to do, but I just don't know how I could go about attacking it. For sure I would have to construct inequalities to act as the constraints, and in this case I'm solving for maximization.

Example: Jimmy is baking cookies for a bake sale. He is making chocolate chip and oatmeal raisin cookies. He gets 25 cents for each chocolate chip cookie and 30 cents for each oatmeal raisin cookie. He cannot make more than 500 cookies of each kind, and he cannot make more than 800 cookies total. He must make at least one-third as many chocolate chip cookies as oatmeal raisin cookies. How many of each kind of cookie should he make to get the most money?

```
 Variables: x = number of chocolate chip cookies (in hundreds)

 y = number of oatmeal raisin cookies (in hundreds)
 Maximization equation: Profit = 25x + 30y

 Constraints:

 1.x≤5
 2.y≤5
 3.x + y≤8
 4.x≥y


 Corners:
 1 and 3: x = 5, x + y = 8. (x, y) = (5, 3).
 2 and 3: y = 5, x + y = 8. (x, y) = (3, 5).
 2 and 4: y = 5, x = y. (x, y) = (, 5).

 Plug into maximization equation:

 (5, 3)Profit = 25(5) + 30(3) = 215.
 (3, 5)Profit = 25(3) + 30(5) = 225.
 (, 5)Profit = 25() + 30(5) = 191.67.


 Thus, the x and y values which maximize the profit are (x, y) = (3, 5). 
 Jimmy should bake 300 chocolate chip cookies and 500 oatmeal raisin 
 cookies.
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: oh yes totally forgot

Comment: None of it's going to sell. No eggs or butter for the cookies and cakes, and the pizza sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would've asked this problem on [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) since this is not a programming problem in the Computer Science sense, but instead a "linear program" in the **mathematical** sense. Anyways, to solve your problem. First assign variables for each of the ingredients:

```
x_1 := Sugar
x_2 := Flour
x_3 := Dried Fruit
x_4 := Chocolate Chips
```

The first four constraints are straightforward:

```
x_1 <= 20
x_2 <= 20
x_3 <= 5
x_4 <= 5
```

We want to maximize profit, so the objective is

```
max.  z = 10(y_1) + 12(y_2) + 14(y_3) + 7(y_4) + 2(y_5)
```

where

```
y_1 = 0.5(x_1) + x_2 + 0.5(x_4)
y_2 = x_1 + 0.5(x_2) + x_3
y_3 = 0.5(x_1) + 2.5(x_3) + 0.25(x_4)
y_4 = 2(x_1)
y_5 = x_1 + 2(x_2) + x_3 + x_4
```

Now substitute `y_1, ..., y_5` into the objective function `z` in order to obtain the objective function as an immediate function of `x_1, ..., x_4`.

Comment: another question: suppose I actually had to use all ingredients, how could I modify the program to fit this constraint?